# Using multiple Objective-C header files in Swift project

Tags: c, swift, objective-c, interop, header-files

I would like to use the AAPLRendererUtils and AAPLMathUtilities files from the [following](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/rendering_reflections_with_fewer_render_passes) Apple sample code in a Swift project.

I have created a bridging header where I have imported "APPLMathUtilities.h" and it works just fine.  However, when I try to import "AAPLRendererUtils.h" I run into issues.

AAPLRendererUtils.h is a header-only file and does not follow the usual Objective-C @interface and @implementation pattern.

AAPLRendererUtils.h also imports APPLMathUtilities.h so maybe this dependency is an issue?

```
#import "AAPLMathUtilities.h"

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct Camera
{
    vector_float3 position;
    vector_float3 target;
    float rotation;
    float aspectRatio;      // width/height
    float fovVert_Half;     // half of vertical field of view, in radians
    float distanceNear;
    float distanceFar;

    matrix_float4x4 GetViewMatrix () const
    {
        return matrix_look_at_left_hand(position, target, (vector_float3){0,1,0});
    }

    matrix_float4x4 GetProjectionMatrix_LH () const
    {
        return matrix_perspective_left_hand (
            fovVert_Half * 2.f,
            aspectRatio,
            distanceNear,
            distanceFar);
    }
};
```

Interestingly, if I comment out the function declarations the code runs but if I leave them in I get the following error:

**field 'GetViewMatrix' declared as a function**

Since you cannot have functions in structs in C am I correct in thinking that Xcode is interpreting this file as a C file?

Comment: It looks like `AAPLRendererUtils` is just a C header, not objective-c. And if so, I believe that you cannot import C header into Swift project directly (not even with the bridge, like objc), you need to create a module, and add it to your swift project.

Comment: It does look for the most part like it is just a C header.  However, there is a section towards the end of the file where the following interface is created: `@interface AAPLActorData : NSObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a C header, it is a C++ header.  The files that this gets included in, in the sample document, all have the ".mm" extension which is Objective-C++.  C++ does allow structs to have methods (it's basically a class where all the members are public, IIRC).  I know a couple of years ago, Swift was not very good at working with C++ files.  I don't know if that's changed.  You could probably separate the methods from the struct to make a C file and a header if you are diligent enough.